# how to have specific image for items of arrays in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

In my Json file i have some array that they about materials of food, when i display them on my recipe page they should have a specific image for each items of materials, but i have a lot of food and and materials so if i do it pure it's so heavy and non-optimal, so i want it respnsive for my codes. Now how can i do it?

this is an example from my object in json file:

```
[{
    "foodName": "pasta",
    "materials": ["tomato","pasta","cheese"],
    "time": "60"
 }
]
```

and i try it from my image component:

```
const Image = {
    tomato: "./tomato.png",
    pasta: "./pasta.png",
    cheese: "./cheese.png"
}
export defualt Image
```

so i import it in my recipe component and map on my json file ti access the materials array for display materials to my use for example like this:

```
material.map((item) => (
        <p>{item}</p>
        <img src={Image[item] alt={item}/>
    ));
```

every thing is okay and i don't have any error but the image is not display but alt is show.

Comment: *"but the image is not display"* - In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, is a request being made for the image?  What is the URL of that request?  Does it match what you expect?  What is the server's response?  Does it match what you expect?  What indication do you have that the response should be any different?

Comment: the status code is 304 and it get error "Cannot destructure property 'foodName' of 'foodPage' as it is undefined.", i use the foodPage and foodName for the make a recipe page for each food and i do that with my json file for access a part of objects in json.

Comment: The *server* is returning that error message?  If that's the case then you'd need to check whatever server-side code is even being invoked by that request for the image file.  That sounds like something entirely custom for this application.  It's also worth noting that the code shown has a syntax error in the JSX and won't even successfully execute, so the code shown wouldn't be producing the output described.  It sounds like you have some further debugging to do in order to narrow this to a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i asking i can find the solution for this problem and i think it can be better to share with you:
everything in this case it's okay but the path of image must be change.
You should put your image in **`public folder`** of your react project and then in the image component get a correct path for each image of items.
for example i make a "image" folder in public folder and make png folder in image folder so my correct path in Image component is:

```
const Image = {
tomato: "/image/png/tomato.png",
pasta: "/image/png/pasta.png",
cheese: "/image/png/cheese.png"} export defualt Image;
```

it will be work.